# Maximum depth exceeded when trying to redirect from child state to parent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state

I am trying to pass data from child to parent state using

I have to state ProjectList and Header, the header(website header) state is the child compenent of parent, there links on header,if it clicks the link then I am getting an id through that link and then passing that id to through redirect.

but it gives me error maximum dept exceeded.The id I want to passs from header to project list is also coming from other state which is not the child of project list.

ProjectList State:

class ProjectList extends React.Component{

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.showDetail=this.showDetail.bind(this);
    this.state={
        category_projects:[],
        projectPage:false,
        clk_project:null,
        category:[]
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/portfolio/get_category_project/`+this.props.match.params.id+'/').then(response => response.json())
        .then(projectsJson => this.setState({category_projects: projectsJson},()=>{
            this.sortProjects()
        }))

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/portfolio/create_category/')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(categoryJson => this.setState({category: categoryJson},()=>{
            this.sortCategory()
        }))

}

sortCategory = ()=>{

    let sortArray=this.state.category;
    let swap;

    for (let i=0;i<sortArray.length;i++)
    {
        for (let j=0;j<sortArray.length;j++){

            if(sortArray[i].category_rank>sortArray[j].category_rank){
                swap=sortArray[i];
                sortArray[i]= sortArray[j];
                sortArray[j]=swap;
            }
        }

    }

    this.setState({category:sortArray})

};

showDetail=(evt)=>{

    evt.preventDefault();

    this.setState({projectPage:true});
    this.setState({clk_project:JSON.parse(evt.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-item'))});


};

sortProjects=()=>{

    let sortArray=this.state.category_projects;
    let swap;

    for (let i=0;i<sortArray.length;i++)
    {
        for (let j=0;j<sortArray.length;j++){

            if(sortArray[i].project_rank>sortArray[j].project_rank){
                swap=sortArray[i];
                sortArray[i]= sortArray[j];
                sortArray[j]=swap;
            }
        }

    }

    this.setState({category_projects:sortArray})

};

render() {

    let redirect=null;

    if (this.state.projectPage){
        redirect=<Redirect to={`/project/${this.state.clk_project.id}`}/>
    }
    return(
        <div>
            {redirect}
            <div className="site_wrapper">

                <div className="clearfix">
                </div>

                <Header category={this.state.category}/>

                <div className="clearfix">
                </div>

                <div className="page_title2">

                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="title"><h2>Projects</h2></div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div className="clearfix">
                </div>

                <div className="container">
                    <br />
                    {this.state.category_projects.map(proj=>{
                        return(
                            <div className="column">
                                <img data-item={JSON.stringify(proj)} onClick={this.showDetail} src={"http://127.0.0.1:8000"+proj.file} alt="Snow" className="ImgWidth"/>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>

                <div className="clearfix margin_top5">
                </div>

                <div className="footer_graph">
                </div>
                <Footer projects={this.state.category_projects} id={this.props.match.params.id}/>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Header State:

```
class Header extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.showCatDetail=this.showCatDetail.bind(this);
    this.state={
        category:[],
        clk_category:[],
        detail:false
    }
}


showCatDetail=(e)=>{

    e.preventDefault();


    this.setState({detail:true,clk_category:JSON.parse(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-item'))},()=>{
        console.log(this.state.clk_category)
    });


};




render(){

    let hreflink=null;
    let redirect=null;

    if (this.state.detail){
        redirect=<Redirect to={`/category_project/${this.state.clk_category.id}`}/>
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {redirect}
            <header id="header">
                <div id="trueHeader">
                    <div className="wrapper">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="logo">
                                <a href={hreflink} id="logo">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="menu_main">
                                <div className="navbar yamm navbar-default">
                                    <div className="container">
                                        <div className="navbar-header">
                                            <div className="visibledevice">
                                                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                                    <li><a href={hreflink} className="active">
                                                        <i className="fa fa-home">
                                                        </i> Home</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
                                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                                <li><a href={hreflink} className="active">
                                                    <i className="fa fa-home">
                                                    </i> Contact Us</a></li>
                                                {this.props.category.map(cat=>{
                                                    return(
                                                        <li data-item={JSON.stringify(cat)} onClick={(e)=>this.showCatDetail(e)}><a href={hreflink} >
                                                            <i className="fa fa-home">
                                                            </i>{cat.category_name}</a></li>
                                                    )
                                                })}
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

this.props.match.params.id this id I want to get from header as I trying to pass from  in header.The this.props.match.params.id in project list can come from Header or other state.Please need suggestion how to pass this id from header to project list as well as the id can comes from other state to project.

Comment: There's over 200 lines of code here, a lot which isn't relevant (irrelevant component functions and markup). Try not to just dump everything, only show relevant parts. Also can you show how you're rendering your routes. It looks like it could be a `react-router` redirect issue

Comment: IMHO, having state at parent and child layers is not a good way to do things, nor is it easily managed.  If you want state at parent and child, look at Redux or the new React Hooks.  If you don't want to try these, then I suggest the parent holds and manages state for all components below it.  The React doc on their website describe how to approach this.